# NSURLConnection delegate methods are called in Simulator but not in Device

Tags: iphone, ios, development-environment

I created a `NSObject`, which downloads some data from a php web service. The problem is that when i run the app in the simulator works well, but in the device the delegate methods are not called. I don´t know why. I write all the delegates methods but none of them are called. This is a part of the `NSObject` code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
 NSLog(@"%@ URL Engine",hostStr);
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

       // while(!finished) {
         //   [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        //}
        [_connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [_connection start];
    });
```

Comment: is `_connection` a strong iVar?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to run this code using the main queue ? If I understood correctly, you want to load the data in a background queue, so you should pass dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) as the first parameter of dispatch_async. Once the data has ben loaded, in your delegate you put something like this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky about call dispatch_async to get the connection run on the main thread queue.

Try this if you want to let your delegates get called on the main thread:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startConnection) 
                        withObject:Nil 
                     waitUntilDone:NO];
```

If you want to let your delegates get called on the other thread, try:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSRunLoop *currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:currentRunLoop forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [connection start];
    [currentRunLoop run];
});
```